# Computing complex or irrational powers of the modular operator

Tags: von-neumann-algebras

Let $M\subset B(H)$ be a von Neumann algebra, with cyclic separating vector $\xi$.

Then the **modular conjugation operator** $S$ is defined to be the closure of the operator $$S_{0}:M\xi\to M\xi\text{ defined by }S_{0}(x\xi) = x^{*}\xi$$

Then the **modular operator** is defined by $\Delta := S^{*}S$.

---

**Now my question is this:**

For a real number $t$, how do we make sense of the expression $\Delta^{it}$?

If we were dealing with bounded operators on a Hilbert space, we could use the Analytic, Continuous, or Borel Functional Calculus.  But since $S$ need not be bounded, it seems we cannot expect $\Delta$ to be.

So what tools are available to assign meaning to $\Delta^{it}$?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct, but instinctively my gut says to use the equation $\langle\Delta^{it}x,x\rangle = \langle\Delta x,x\rangle^{it}$.

Since a bounded operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is completely determined by the behaviour of $\langle Tx,x\rangle$ for all $x\in H$, I see no reason not to expect this to apply to unbounded operators as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive unbounded operators satisfy the Spectral Theorem, so Borel functional calculus applies to them.

Comment: Is it the same definition then?  $\Delta^{it} = \int_{\sigma(\Delta)}\lambda^{it}E(d\lambda)$, where $E$ is the spectral measure of $\Delta$?

Comment: I can't find an exact reference, but when you say "satisfy the spectral theorem", do you just mean that they have spectral measures?

Comment: Yes, that there exists $E$ such that $\Delta \xi=\int_{\sigma(\Delta)}\lambda\,dE(\lambda)\xi$. for every $\xi$ in the domain of $\Delta$.